# Writing links without including protocol

Tags: php, html, hyperlink, protocols

I have a website that can be viewed in both the `http` and `https` protocols, the problem here being that the links and assets must reflect the protocol that the website is being viewed over.

One solution would be to use relative links, however due to particular reasons, I cannot use relative links, resultantly, I have had to find an alternative...

I have recently learned that you can write a link like so in order use the current protocol:

```
<a href="//www.example.net/test/">Test</a>
```

Up until now I have been using the following:

```
<?php

    // Get the current protocol
    $_PROTOCOL = $_SERVER['HTTPS']=='on' ? 'https://' : 'http://';

?>

<a href="<?php echo $_PROTOCOL; ?>www.example.net/test/">Test</a>
```

Whilst the first solution works, I have only recently discovered it am not familiar with how it works and whether it is reliable. I am aware that older browsers may not like it, but this does not bother me as it is only very old browsers (apparently).

When I tried to generate a sitemap for one of my websites, the urls were written very oddly like so:

```
http://beta.example.net///venue/
```

Instead of

```
http://beta.example.net/venue/
```

Why is this? Is this because of the links I am using?

Is my original (PHP) solution better, despite the large amount of code to go with it?

Comment: It's better to use "//example.net/test". Even Google's CDN uses this format - https://developers.google.com/speed/libraries/devguide#jquery so you can be sure it works across all browsers

Comment: What is the problem with your php solution? the only thing i would change is to store the `PROTOCOL` in constant instead of variable, then you could use it across different scopes of your site and it will be more convenient 
`define("PROTOCOL",$_SERVER["HTTPS"]=="on"?"https":"http");`

Comment: @YaronUliel There is nothing wrong with my PHP solution, but the HTML solution is much easier and requires much less code. I do not want to have to write `echo $_PROTOCOL` for every link in my website!! The advice with regards to using a constant is good though so +1 :-)

Comment: I think that you are quiet exaggerating with the amount of code needed in order to do it - it is not like you don't need to write the links anyway. And yeah - I totally agree with you that client-side based solution (if it fits your requirements in this case) is better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use "//example.net" anywhere you want to use a regular URL, and it's a format according to the standard §4.2. RFC 3986.

---

However, if you still want to change the scheme of a URL in a clean manner, you can use `http_build_url`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-url.php

like this:

```
http_build_url("http://yoururl.org", array('scheme'=>'https')); // changes to https://
```

Comment: I merely told you how you can change the scheme in a simple manner, with less effort than doing a <?php echo $_PROTOCOL;?>. You can use "//example.net" just fine, btw

Comment: Thank you, please can you amend your answer to include the information about `//example.net` because this is what I am interested in :-)

Answer (score 0):

The wrong links in sitemap are because the generator is wrong. Best solution is to update the sitemap generator to work as it should. Simple solution is to use $protocol.

Comment: Editing the urls generated by the sitemap is not an issue, will take me a second. I simply wanted to know whether it is better to use `PHP` or the HTML method?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide code that would reproduce the problem you described with the links showing extra slashes. My guess is the code you're using tries to assemble the entire URI and there are trailing/leading slashes in the parts you're concatenating.

The $_SERVER['HTTPS'] variable isn't guaranteed to be set to "on", just so that you know the defined behavior. It's just set to a non-false value [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php), but that shouldn't be an issue in the code you supplied here.

Using a protocol relative URL is definitely preferable to having PHP do extra work to rebuild your URIs with every request, and is also prone to error. I would recommend using protocol relative URLs where you feel they are needed, but generally speaking you are advised to build your site from the ground-up to either use HTTPS or not. The protocol relative URLs may still cause some browsers (like IE, for example) to issue a warning or inform the user that the SSL for the page is broken.

You want to always check these things and test them out thoroughly when you require secure transfer. It's easy to accidentally slip in an http://foobar.com/img.jpg or inadvertently send an AJAX request over HTTP instead of HTTPS and suddenly the SLL icon for that page is now broken in the user's browser.

Comment: The code is there that produces the wierd links is there! `<a href="//example.net/test/"`>Test</a>` As simple as that. It is most likely the sitemap generator is broken. I didn't think that the server variable was reliable, that is one of the reasons why I asked this question

Comment: That code by itself wouldn't cause the result you described, no. It is likely your problem manifests itself somewhere else.

Comment: Try it yourself, go to http://rapid.searchmetrics.com/seo-tools/extras/sitemap-generator,25.html,result#r and enter a url with these links! It may also be to do with the `.htaccess` rewrites

Comment: I was not aware you were using some third party tool to generate these URLs, nor was there any mention of this in the question. My assumption was that you were using the PHP code demonstrated above, which does not reproduce this problem. I also can't see how the problem gets produced using the link you supplied. So there's not enough information for me to reproduce that problem and help you debug it.

Comment: Don't worry I dont need to debug it, I just wanted to make sure it wasnt my page that was generating the bad links and this appears to be the case so I am not bothered about it :-)